# Weird Fragment lifecycle when Jetpacks Navigation component is used

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack

So I've an `Activity` in which I set my navigation graph and `NavigationView`. So each menu item is a `Fragment`. Problem lies in the issue, that if I open `menu item A`, then open navigation drawer and choose `menu item A` again, it recreates the view - so far normal, but when I log out the lifecycle of the fragment, it works like this:

```
onCreate(), ... , [choose same menu item again], onCreate(), onDestroy(), onDetach()
```

Why does onDestroy and onDetach are the last called lifecycle methods? It would make sense if the fragment would be removed, but it is visible to user, so onDestroy should happen after user chooses menu item second time and should end with onCreate method. Any idea what is causing this?